# How do I ensure I a specific node is loaded and available with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within a hotel [booking](https://be.synxis.com/?adult=1&arrive=2019-07-24&chain=14789&child=0&currency=GBP&depart=2019-07-26&hotel=7812&level=hotel&locale=en-US&rooms=1&sbe_ri=0), I'm trying to grab, via injecting javascript using the cjs chrome extension, the available rooms and rates upon loading the page and whenever the user changes the dates. I tried using `$(window).on("load", function)`, to wait for all the assets to load, but that doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. I would sometimes have to refresh the page a few times to get it working.

This is currently my code. With `window.onload`, I would execute the function `grabInfo`.

```
const grabInfo = () => {
  const availableData = window._globalTracking;
  let availableRooms = [];
  availableData.AvailableRooms.map(room => {
    let newRoomObj = {
      roomCode: room.RoomCode,
      rateCode: room.RateCode,
      roomName: room.RoomName,
      price: room.Price
    };
    availableRooms.push(newRoomObj);
  });
  console.log(
    `Check-in: ${availableData.ArrivalDtMMDDYYYY} Check-out: ${
      availableData.DepartDtMMDDYYYY
    }`
  );
  console.log('Rooms and Rates: ', availableRooms);
};

// when window has loaded everything, perform the following
$(window).on('load', function() {
  grabInfo();
  // listen for changes to dom (specifically the hotels cards changing to grab new data)
  let targetNodes = $('.thumb-cards_products');
  let myObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationHandler);
  let obsConfig = {
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true
  };

  myObserver.observe(targetNodes[0], obsConfig);
});
```

I thought maybe I could use `$('.thumb-cards_products').on("ready",function())`, to wait for that targetted element to load but that doesn't seem to work.

While `window.onready` works, it's not consistent and `$('.thumb-cards_products').on("ready",function())` doesn't work at all. In the end, I'm trying to get data specifically from `window._globalTracking.AvailableRooms`, which is most likely returned from an asynchronous api call.

Comment: The `window.onready` event fires when the page is ready, which is unrelated with the card info load, since the cards load asynchronous by a javascript code.

Comment: @GramThanos would it make sense for me to have a listener that waits for card elements to be available or is there a better way to wait until that actual api returns the desired info?

Comment: There is not such an event. Follow the Daron Spaulding 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting an interval that polls for the desired content, once its available you can run your function

```
function callback() {
   if ($('myElement').length) {
       clearInterval(token);
       grabInfo();

       let targetNodes = $('.thumb-cards_products');
       let myObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationHandler);
       let obsConfig = {
               childList: true,
               characterData: true,
               attributes: true,
               subtree: true
           };

       myObserver.observe(targetNodes[0], obsConfig);
}

const token = window.setInterval(callback, 200);
```